# Telethon: The client does not catch events UserUpdate()

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

The client does not catch events UserUpdate() for some users

```
@client.on(events.UserUpdate())
async def normal_handler(event):
# For some users, events are not caught here (online status)
...
```

What I found out:

- These users are in the account's address book.
- I can get an ID using both the phone number and the username.
- On different clients (**telethon**) all the same
- Even on mobile and desktop applications, the online status of these users is not updated until you close/open the chat.

This is not a problem with **telethon**, The problem is somewhere higher.
There is an assumption that something is wrong with the ID. Perhaps the reason is deleting the user and re-registering.
Or in some user settings.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If Telegram is not sending the update, Telethon cannot call your handlers either. You can confirm this by using `events.Raw`. If Telegram doesn't send the update, there is not much you can do.

Comment: I understand it. How to solve this problem. Why doesn't telegram send data, is this a bug (Will Telegram developers solve this problem?)?

Comment: Probably not. Only messages are meant to be reliable. Any other status information is available as a best-effort and Telegram decides when it's relevant.

Comment: The client receives event notifications through almost all contacts. I don't think they manually send notifications.  Or there are special conditions in the algorithm for someone not to send out events.